# Are there any Christian sects that allow for the existence of other "God" claims?

Tags: nature-of-god, denomination-survey, polytheism

Are there any Christian sects that allow for the existence of other "God" claims?  That is, allow for claims that are (semi-)polytheistic in nature.  I'm excluding claims that the Trinity is polytheistic for purposes of this question.

I may have just found my answer. It turns out Mormonism allows for the existence of other "Gods" – their afterlife claims include the belief that they become "Gods".  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Are there any *other* Christian sects that allow for multiple "God" claims?

Comment: Why did you wish to exclude the trinity concept? Some see the doctrine of the trinity and Godhead as being polytheistic in nature as well.

Comment: I only exclude it because I'm more familiar with that discussion.  I'm trying to see if there are additional polytheistic concepts I'm unaware of.

Comment: do you mean like how catholics pray to the virgin Mary and other saints for miracles?

Comment: @AaronKorn If those saints are considered "Gods" within that framework, than yes.  I was under the impression that is not the case but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose some would consider [Unitarian Universalists](http://www.uua.org/beliefs/welcome/index.shtml) to be a Christian sect, and they certainly allow for belief in other gods.